# Set combobox items based on another combobox values

Tags: c#

So i have 2 comboboxes, a state one and a city one.
I want when the user selects a state from first combobox, the second combobox update with the cities that are inside that state. This is the code.
Just so you know, oras means city and judet means state

````
public void change_OrasBox_items()
        {
            OrasBox.Items.Clear();
            switch (JudetBox_item)
            {
                case "Alba":
                    OrasBox.Items.Add("Alba-Iulia");
                    OrasBox.Text = "Alba-Iulia";
                    break;
                case "Teleorman":
                    OrasBox.Items.Add("Rosiori De Vede");
                    OrasBox.Text = "Rosiori De Vede";
                    break;
            }
        }

public void JudetBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (JudetBox_item != JudetBox.SelectedItem.ToString())//This will control your changes in JudetBox about selected item and call change_OrasBox_items()
            {
                JudetBox_item = JudetBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                change_OrasBox_items();
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Hi @AlinBalan, what's wrong with the code you have now? Are you getting errors? Is it not doing what you expect, and if so what different output do you expect?

Comment: When i m selecting the "Alba" from JudetBox nothing happens, i mean it selects the Alba but nothing is changing on the OrasBox, i expect when i select Alba from JudetBox the OrasBox should change on Alba-Iulia

Comment: did you trace the code to see if the indexChanded function runs correctly or not?

Comment: Im not sure how to do that ..

Comment: What to look for ?

Comment: which IDE do you working with?

Comment: Im using visual studio 2019 if that's what u want to know

Comment: you can set break points and run under debug, so you can check for possible problems. i checked your code, it's correct. maybe the problem is with "JudetBox_item" initiated value. It's better to be an empty string.

Comment: JudetBox_item is declared as a string, an empty string

Comment: I checked your code completely, it's ok. the other possibility might be mistyping of "JudetBox" initiated items.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SelectedItem` property of `OrasBox`:

```c#
case "Alba":
    OrasBox.Items.Add("Alba-Iulia");
    OrasBox.SelectedItem = "Alba-Iulia";
    break;
```

Or you can set `OrasBox.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: I already tried that and nothing is working, i think the problem is the properties of my combobox, can you check them for me please ? 
AutoCompleteMode: SuggestAppend
AutoCompleteSource: ListItems
DropDownStyle: DropDownList
JudetBox.MaxDropDownItems = 5;
            JudetBox.IntegralHeight = false;
            JudetBox.MaxDropDownItems = 5;
            JudetBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            JudetBox.Name = "";
            JudetBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 81);
            JudetBox.TabIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you bind the object source to the comboBox datasource so that there can be efficiency in your `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedValue`
Something like this

```
myComboBox.DataSource = new List<yourClass>();
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayPropertyName";
myComboBox.ValueMember = yourClass.Id;
```

Whenever the selected index changes, you can just call

```
myComboBox.SelecteValue();
```

and then you will get the right thing.